# Libgdx audio wav file not playing soundpool not ready?

Tags: android, audio, libgdx

I am trying to add sound to my Libgdx game using a wav file.  It is supposed to play in the background of the main menu and loop but for some reason it does not play.  Does anyone have any insight into way this may be.  I also notice in the logcat that soundpool is not ready.  I have added the following code to the constructor of my screen and the file is located in my assets folder.  Thanks.

```
Sound wavSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sound.wav"));
    wavSound.play();
```

Comment: Die you try to use music instead if sound? If it's a song you shouldn't use sound. It is used to play short effects.

Comment: No I am using sound because it is a really short clip a couple of seconds long.

Comment: I have noticed that the sound is working if I add it on button touch.  It just doesn't start playing automatically when the screen loads.

Comment: It works using music.  Its not exactly what I wanted to use since its such a short clip but it will do.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file extension is named correctly and that the file is encoded in the proper format.

Renaming sound.mp3 to sound.wav will trigger a SoundPool: Not Ready error.